# How to set value of a TextView in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I am using fragments in my dynamic application, where the User.java file contains the values and `TabbedActivity.java` file contains three fragments. I want to set the text to `TextView` in `ProfileFrgament.java`. So, I created a `TextView` in `fragment_profile.xml` and referenced it from `TabbedActivity.java` file with the following code

```
    name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    //getting the current user
    User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser();
    //setting values to textviews
    name.setText(user.getUsername());
```

It does not shows any compilation error, but after opening `TabbedActivity.java`, the app stops with NullPointerException at line `name.setText(user.getUsername());` How to solve this issue?

This is the code of `ProfileFragment.java` file

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    name = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name);
    //getting the current user
    User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getUser();
    //setting values to textviews
    name.setText(user.getUsername());

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Exactly, Your textview is availabe in `fragment_profile.xml` and you find that textview in `TabbedActivity.java` and set, so NullpointerException occured.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani So, what's the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TextView` is in `fragment_profile.xml` and you trying to find that `TextView` in `TabbedActivity.java`, so `NullPointerException` is occured

Put this code in `ProfileFrgament.java`

Change your code with this one

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getUser(); 
    name.setText(user.getUsername()); 

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: It is showing error on line `User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser();` saying **getInstance() in sharedPrefManager cannot be applied to  ProfileFragment**

Comment: Replace this with getActivity()

Comment: It is now showing `name = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name);` as **unreachable statement**

Comment: `unreachable statement` because you write that code after return.

Comment: Now, no compilation error, but app still stops with logcat `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at net.softglobe.arsoddynamic.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:30)`

Comment: We can not help you unless you post necessary code here.

Comment: I have updated the question with code of `ProfileFragment.java`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in the fragment's java file than in the activity's java file.
Now for finding view in fragment. 
Replace this code :

```
name = findViewById(R.id.name);
```

to :

```
name = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Rest of the code can be written as it is already.

Also put this type of operation in `onViewCreated` method. Putting this code in `onCreateView` may crash the app.

Comment: The line `setText()` now showing as **unreachable statement**

Comment: please update the question with the new code you have written.

Comment: I've updated question with code of `ProfileFragment.java`

Comment: put that code in `onViewCreated` method. Don't do anything in `onCreateView` apart from inflating `fragment` layout.